# How to group Boxplots without use of color or fill in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataset that I would like to create two groups of boxplots using the `ggplot2` package as shown below:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(f1=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("m","w")), 
                 f2=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("young","old")),
                 boxthis=rnorm(100))
ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = f1), data = df) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

BUT, I want to color the boxplots using a different aesthetic (not shown) or not color them at all. How can I group the `old` and `young` together, but still have separate boxplots for the `f1` variable. This is a simplified version of what I want to do, so I ask that your answer be expandable to multiple samples (e.g. more than just `old` and `young`, maybe 20 different categories).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `group` mapping:

```
ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, group = interaction(f1,f2)),
  data = df) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about interaction().

Comment: So this solution has led to a new question. How do I get the x axis label to display both age (young and old) and the sex (M and F)?

Comment: can you post a new question (you can link back to this one)?

Comment: (you could try  `x=interaction(f1,f2)`, but that will leave all the boxplots evenly spaced, which you might not want)