# How to plot multiple boxplots with numeric x values properly in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get a boxplot with 3 different tools in each dataset size like the one below:

[image]

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x = dataset, y = time, color = tool)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  labs(x = 'Datasets', y = 'Seconds', title = 'Time') + 
  scale_y_log10() +  theme_bw()
```

But I need to transform x-axis to log scale. For that, I need to numericize each dataset to be able to transform them to log scale. Even without transforming them, they look like the one below:

[image]

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x = dataset, y = time, color = tool)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  labs(x = 'Datasets', y = 'Seconds', title = 'Time') + 
  scale_y_log10() + theme_bw()
```

I checked boxplot parameters and grouping parameters of aes, but could not resolve my problem. At first, I thought this problem is caused by scaling to log, but removing those elements did not resolve the problem.

What am I missing exactly? Thanks...

Files are [in this link.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ayk7gTCJ6E6Zv-kP-h8pOEExP3pJivBr) "data2" is the numericized version of "data1".

Comment: try `ggplot(data2, aes(x = factor(dataset), ...`

Comment: @PoGibas the problem is, I want to represent my data with their numeric value on x axis. I can't make it log-scale if I factorize the axis.

Comment: First log2 and the factorize

Comment: @PoGibas If I plot with factorized x-axis, they will have equal space between each other. That is why I want to leave x-axis as numeric, and already log2+factorize did plot in a wrong way, just like I experienced before.

Comment: @Batu Have you tried setting `position="dodge"` in the `geom_boxplot` function ? This should group your outputs.

Comment: @RoB I tried after your suggestion, but it did not work out. It gave a warning message saying "position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals". My result is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3xs1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was a tough cookie, but I learned something new from it!

Just using `group = dataset` is not sufficient because you also have the `tool` variable to look out for. After digging around a bit, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41390627/6478701) which made use of the `interaction()` function.

This is the trick that was missing. You want to use `group` because you are not using a factor for the `x` values, but you need to include `tool` in the separation of your data (hence using `interaction()` which will compute the possible crosses between the 2 variables).

```
# This is for pretty-printing the axis labels
my_labs <- function(x){
  paste0(x/1000, "k")
}
levs <- unique(data2$dataset)

ggplot(data2, aes(x = dataset, y = time, color = tool, 
                  group = interaction(dataset, tool))) + 
  geom_boxplot() + labs(x = 'Datasets', y = 'Seconds', title = 'Time') +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = levs, labels = my_labs) + # define a log scale with your axis ticks
  scale_y_log10() + theme_bw()
```

This plots

[image]